# How to estimate cutoff point for continuous varibles and binary output?

Tags: regression, logistic, estimation, binary-data, signal-processing

I have a simulated dataset comprising signals (binary) and a set of continuous inputs. When the continuous var goes up over than a threshold, the system is switched on, which means that the signal outputs 1 in this case.

Usually the continuous variable doesn't increase that much and stay below the threshold, the signal outputs 0. My problem is given a dataset of signals and continuous input variables, how can I estimate the threshold for the continuous variables? What if some independent variables are dependent on each other?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How many continuous variables are you dealing with? Also, is the relation between the continuous input and the binary output a probabilistic one or a deterministic one?